# Zeppelin Interpreter throws null pointer exception

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am running few notebooks in EMR zeppelin.

`EMR version 5.29.0`
`Spark 2.4.4 and Zeppelin 0.8.2`
At times there won't be sufficient memory to run a notebook since multiple notebooks are running parallel. Hence, it will throw an error like below.

```
 INFO [2021-03-30 06:14:51,383] ({pool-2-thread-99} Paragraph.java[jobRun]:381) - Run paragraph [paragraph_id: 20210325-112126_1343087125, interpreter: pyspark, note_id: 2G34X6W7Z, user: admin]
ERROR [2021-03-30 06:14:51,385] ({pool-2-thread-99} Job.java[run]:190) - Job failed
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:136)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:312)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:408)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    ... 13 more
ERROR [2021-03-30 06:14:51,385] ({pool-2-thread-99} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2308) - Error
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:141)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:136)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:312)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:408)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    ... 13 more
 WARN [2021-03-30 06:14:51,386] ({pool-2-thread-99} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2316) - Job 20210325-112126_1343087125 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException, result: %text java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:170)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:62)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.callRemoteFunction(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:133)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.internal_create(RemoteInterpreter.java:169)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.open(RemoteInterpreter.java:136)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:312)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:408)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

 INFO [2021-03-30 06:14:51,401] ({pool-2-thread-99} VFSNotebookRepo.java[save]:196) - Saving note:2G34X6W7Z
 INFO [2021-03-30 06:14:51,775] ({pool-2-thread-99} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:120) - Job 20210325-112126_1343087125 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter-iwb::2G34X6W7Z-shared_session
```

Once this issue occurs, even if the memory is available at a later stage the notebook would not run until the zeppelin service is restarted. We have tried to run the notebook when the entire yarn resource was free, but the notebook throws the same error. The issue persists until the interpreter/zeppelin is restarted. We cannot run the same notebook until then.

Comment: Are these logs from the notebook? Do you have access to the zeppelin server logs?

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is from zeppelin server log. I have access to the server logs.